# SuperType Table of subtype objects not showing added attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe

I am trying to make a supertype table of objects that holds subtype objects, but the bottom line insert once ran shows the first two attributes SSN and name as inserted. Is Oracle Express just broken these days? or is there something wrong in my code?

```
create or replace type PersonType as object (
  SSN number (9),
  name varchar2(30))
  Instantiable
  NOT Final;

create or replace type TenantType under PersonType (
  aptNum REF ApartmentType,
  phone number(10),
  car varchar2(15),
  contract varchar2(10));
  Instantiable
  Final;

create or replace type EmployeeType under PersonType (
  empId number(4),
  empAdr varchar2(40));
  Instantiable
  Final;

create table P1 of PersonType (
  constraint P1_SSN_pk Primary Key (SSN));

insert into P1 values(TenantType(956785252, 'Jerry Wilson', (select ref(a) from A1 a where aptNum = 110), 8015167895, 'Toyota', '8 months'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run simple select you see common values of supertype. When creating types you can add member function to display subtypes in different ways or you can use [`treat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/functions-and-operators-useful-with-objects.html#GUID-5C6151A6-13C5-42A6-8182-77FC7957C8B5):

```
select treat(value(p) as tenanttype) from p1 p where p.ssn = 956785252
```

You have typos (unnecessary semicolons in type definitions) and missing definition of `ApartmentType` and table `a1`, so here are my test data: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9967aa8c7d3677f206c7d41612faf63)

And here are examples of mentioned member function `show()`: [Inheritance in SQL Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/inheritance-in-sql-object-types.html#GUID-76F4F2F9-A239-442D-97C3-678FE9330F45)